# Magento 2 common css variables not applied for third party modules

Tags: magento2.4.1, variables

I am using a custom theme, declared common variables under,

app\design\frontend\Zero\my_theme\web\css\source\components

**1) _variables.less**

Eg:

```
@h1__font-size: 48px !important;
```

**2) common.less**

Eg:

```
h1 {
    font-size:@h1__font-size !important; 
}
```

I am using magefan extension, if i use **@h1__font-size** in blog pages, its not working its returns **@h1__font-size variable is undefined**, how to solve this error.